# Structured Spark streaming metrics retrieval

Tags: apache-spark, streaming, spark-structured-streaming

I have an application with structured Spark streaming and I would like to get some metrics like scheduling delay, latency, etc. Usually, such metrics can be found in Spark UI Streaming tab, however, such functionality does not exist for structured streaming as far as I know. 
So how can I get these metrics values?

For now, I have tried to use query progress but not all of the required metrics can be found in the results:

```
QueryProgress {
  "timestamp" : "2019-11-19T20:14:07.011Z",
  "batchId" : 1,
  "numInputRows" : 8,
  "inputRowsPerSecond" : 0.8429038036034138,
  "processedRowsPerSecond" : 1.1210762331838564,
  "durationMs" : {
    "addBatch" : 6902,
    "getBatch" : 1,
    "getEndOffset" : 0,
    "queryPlanning" : 81,
    "setOffsetRange" : 20,
    "triggerExecution" : 7136,
    "walCommit" : 41
  },
  "stateOperators" : [ {
    "numRowsTotal" : 2,
    "numRowsUpdated" : 2,
    "memoryUsedBytes" : 75415,
    "customMetrics" : {
      "loadedMapCacheHitCount" : 400,
      "loadedMapCacheMissCount" : 0,
      "stateOnCurrentVersionSizeBytes" : 17815
    }
  } ],
  "sources" : [ {
    "description" : "KafkaV2[Subscribe[tweets]]",
    "startOffset" : {
      "tweets" : {
        "0" : 579
      }
    },
    "endOffset" : {
      "tweets" : {
        "0" : 587
      }
    },
    "numInputRows" : 8,
    "inputRowsPerSecond" : 0.8429038036034138,
    "processedRowsPerSecond" : 1.1210762331838564
  } ]
```

Comment: I'm not sure about this, but did you try using Spark listener to get the metrics?

Comment: Yep, this is the result of Spark query listener metrics retrieval

Comment: _"scheduling delay"_ is the difference between the timestamps of two consecutive query progresses. _"latency"_ is simply the latency in a query progress. Are there any other metrics you'd like to get at?

Comment: @JacekLaskowski Is there a separate latency metric that should be configured with listener? As far as I understood there is a driver.latency metric but it is not in the query listener results

Comment: Sorry, but looks like I'm more confused after these two new questions. What's _"a separate latency metric that should be configured with listener"_? What's _"driver.latency metric"_? I've never seen it before.

Comment: I mean that I don't see in this output latency metric. Although, I've read in the documentation that there is a latency metric which is set up by default

Answer (score 0):

You are right, these metrics were, at some point, not available in Structured Streaming **(until some version of Spark 3, now, there's the "Structured Streaming" tab, in Spark 2 this tab isn't available)**, but they were indeed available in Spark UI, when you used `DStream`s in the "Streaming" tab.

You could also get them from `StreamingListener` if you registered it with `StreamingContext`, but you can no longer do that with `SparkSession`, so, you can only use `StreamingQueryListener`.

**But!** All the info for computing these metrics is available in the `durationMs` map of your json.

If you add up all the values in this map, you get the total processing time (or, as you call it `latency`) of your microbatch in milliseconds.

As for `scheduling delay`, if I understand correctly what that means, you'd have to add up everything that happens before the `triggerExecution` phase. But you'll have to do some digging to understand what happens before it.

So, you have these operations:

`addBatch`,
`getBatch`,
`getEndOffset`,
`queryPlanning`,
`setOffsetRange`,
`triggerExecution`,
`walCommit` (btw these names are from Spark 2 and some of them changed in Spark 3).

You have to add up the operations that happen before `triggerExecution` and you get your `scheduling delay`, like I said, but you have to study the `MicroBatchExecution` class of Spark to figure that out. So, this is "type" of `scheduling delay` is basically the amount of type it took before the actual execution of the microbatch was started.

In the `MicroBatchExecution` class search for `reportTimeTaken` and you will see the same exact operations that you have in your `durationMs` map. Now, you just have to figure out their order.

P.S. I took a quick look at `MicroBatchExecution`, and it seems like the only operation that goes after `triggerExecution` is `addBatch`, it belongs to the `Sink` trait and is responsible for writing data to sink. So, it seems like `scheduling delay` can be computed by adding up everything from `durationMs` except for `triggerExecution` and `addBatch`.

Another option would be to build Spark from source, add `println` statements there after each `reportTimeTaken` statement and see the order of these operations when you run your Spark Structured Streaming job.